# how to provide path in php to run .exe file which is not in same directory?

Tags: php, path

i am using wamp server.i need to run a .exe file from php file , they are not in same directory.php file is in C:\wamp\www\Final Code and .exe file is in C:\wamp\www\Final Code\Database. What is the code to provide path to that .exe file . plz help

Comment: shell_exec("Main.exe"); this works if they are in same directory

Comment: Just write in the full path of the exe file with c:\..

Comment: Why don't you just [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php)?

Answer (score 1):

You can see this in example 3: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php